# Can't upload an image to a Linux server via Phonegap and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, cordova, nginx, phonegap

I am making an app in **PhoneGap** that requires an image to be uploaded to a Linux server. I set up a test **CentOS 7 VM** and installed and configured the **LEMP** stack on it and then created a *php* script called `upload.php` (below). This script was just taken off of the INTERNET from multiple different tutorials and I just edited the path to save the file to my desired location.

I then created my javascript code to upload it to the server but it wasn't working so I just took the code from the online tutorial just for testing purposes to see if it was working properly (also below). I get the alert which indicates that it is working but no image was being uploaded so I tried disabling my firewall but still no luck.

I'm not sure if it is the server setup, the javascript, the php or just my ISP. Any help is much appreciated.

I am using the cordova plugins:
Camera

File

File transfer

---

**PHP:**

`<?php
    $new_image_name = urldecode($_FILES["file"]["name"]).".jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/upload/".$new_image_name);
?>`

**Javascript:**

```js
navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
 alert('get picture failed');
 }, {
 quality: 100,
 destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
 });
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
 var options = new FileUploadOptions();
 options.fileKey = "file";
 options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
 console.log(options.fileName);
 var params = new Object();
 params.value1 = "test";
 params.value2 = "param";
 options.params = params;
 options.chunkedMode = false;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
 ft.upload(imageURI, "http://192.168.1.11/upload.php", function(result){
 alert(JSON.stringify(result));
alert('works');
 }, function(error){
 console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
alert('doesnt');
 }, options);
 }
```

Comment: What happens? What do your logs say? Have you set the correct permissions to allow php to write to the upload directory?

Comment: @miknik I temporarily changed the permissions to 777 for the upload directory and I'm getting the same result. It says it was successful by alerting works instead of doesn't but the file doesn't get saved. in the _JSON.stringify(result)_ alert I get: **bytesSent: 621268, responseCode: 200, response: "objectID"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few problems that needed to be overcome. All of which were fairly simple.

I was using an absolute path but php interpreted it as a relative path so I just changed the path.

The directory also was owned by root so i fixed that using `chown nginx:nginx uploads`

The firewall was blocking access from my phone so I disabled the firewall but still need to come up with a better solution. I'm sure it's fairly simple but I haven't got round to it yet.